# how to replace more than one matched string in Emacs Regexp?

Tags: regex, emacs

In Emacs Regexp, I'm doing a replace-regexp, searching for this

`<span class="small">\([^<]+\)</span>\([^<]+\)<span class="small">\([^<]+\)</span>`

and trying to replace it with this

`<span class="small">\1\2</span>`

I'm trying to concatenate the two matched strings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you're having a bunch of regexp issues. I highly recommend using `M-x re-builder` (aka `regexp-builder`) which lets you interactively build a regexp while dynamically showing you (in the buffer from which you called it) what the pattern and each sub-group is matching. For documentation, see the commentary in `M-x find-library RET re-builder RET`, as well as using `C-h m` from the re-builder buffer to see the available key bindings. You *will* need to be sure you understand the different syntaxes -- especially "read" vs "string" -- otherwise backslashes may cause confusion.

Comment: @phils Thanks, you're right, regexp-builder is really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a description of how it doesn't work for you, I can only guess that you intended to replace with `\1\3` rather than `\1\2`.

A second possibility is that the text you are operating on doesn't actually match your regex.

```
(switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "nst.html"))
(insert "<span class=\"small\">foo</span>bar<span class=\"small\">baz</span>")
(goto-char (point-min))
(replace-regexp
  "<span class=\"small\">\\([^<]+\\)</span>\\([^<]+\\)<span class=\"small\">\\([^<]+\\)</span>"
 "<span class=\"small\">\\1\\3</span>")
```

Try `M-x undo` in the buffer to see what it looked like before the replacement operation.

(I suppose losing the text in `\2` is your intention?)

Comment: Also, since they're not using \2, the second matcher part doesn't need \( and \) around it. Then \1\2 will work.